# Global variable changes to 0

Tags: netlogo

I have a to-report that divide a range into 11 steps, like this:

```
to-report random11steps
  let step random 11 + 1 
  let step-value (minLM / 11) 
  let rnd 0
  repeat step [ 
    set rnd (rnd + step-value)
  ]
  report rnd
end
```

where `minLM` is a global variable set to 0.005. When I run the procedure `minLM` changes to be '0.
If I substitute `minLM` by `0.005` the function works but I do not know why `minLM` changes to `0`.

Besides, is there any primitive to make the code of this procedure a bit shorter?

Regards

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. This function is not changing `minLM`; look elsewhere.
2. Don't write functions that depend on global variables unless absolutely necessary; pass `minLM` as an argument.
3. It is unclear why you want to use repeated addition instead of multiplication.  That is, you could just return `(step * step-value)`.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. No. The value of `minLM` is a constant or fixed parameter. Point 3. you are correct.

Comment: @user1993416 It is still better to write your function so that it takes an argument rather than depending on a global.  (Also, I don't understand your "No".)

Comment: thank you very much. What I meant to say with my answer is that the value of `minLM` is a constant and is not altered in the code in any line. I have defined `set minLM 0.005` in the setup and the value is not altered afterwards. I do not know what I am missing and why the minLM is 0 and not 0.005.

Comment: You did not post enough code to determine this, but only enough to confirm that your `random11steps` is not the source of the problem.  But, make sure your `clear-all` command in your setup comes at the very beginning.  It resets all globals to `0`.